# JQuery Validation Plugin Doesn't Work With Simple Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using JQuery validation plugin to validate forms in my application. It works well when the button is of type 'submit'. However, I have one form in which I need the data to be submitted using JQuery.Ajax, hence I am using simple `<input type='button'>`. But then the validation wont work.
Here's the working code-

```
<head>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#some_form").validate({});  
 }); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name='some_form' id='some_form'>
<!--  Form Fields -->
<input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
</body>
```

The above code works, however, when I put this in the code `<input type='button' value='Submit'>`, it doesn't work.

Does anybody has any idea how to get this working?

Comment: hi, i think you need to give **name** and **id** element to submit button..

Comment: are u sure the validate() is going to be given as validate({})...

Comment: @lakshmipriya yes, I dont think that's the problem, since the code works fine with a submit button

Comment: did u check by giving method=post or get...

Comment: @lakshmipriya How does that matter when button type is not `submit` ?

Comment: it may be because A submit button sends form data to a server by default... but type=button is basically an input tag which is used as clickable button... to make it execute u have to give a onclick or some other method...

Comment: @lakshmipriya Exactly. So when I have `<input type='button'>` it should not matter whether the form has post or get method, because form data will be sent by Ajax

Comment: casperOne, what is unreal about this question??? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the jQuery validation plugin is designed to only work when a submit is triggered; thus when you have the type "button" on your input element, the form isn't actually submitted and hence the validation never runs. Is there a reason you don't want to have the 'submit' type?

Edit to address comment: To use ajax, but still have a 'submit' button type, you use the 'submitHandler' option of the plugin arguments ... like this:

```
$("#some_form").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
         ... ajax stuff here ...
    }
});
```

This will override the actual posting of the form, but will still trigger the submit event so that the validation gets run.

Comment: well I want to use Ajax, I don't want the page to get refreshed when the data is submitted

Answer (score 1):

Allright! I guess I found the answer. So I am posting it here in case anyone needs it. Here's the code

```
<head>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button_id').click( function() {
    if ($("#some_form").validate().form() == true)
        {
            // Call Ajax Here
        }
  });  
});  
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name='some_form' id='some_form'>
<!--  Form Fields -->
<input type='button' id='button_id' value='Submit'>
</form>
</body>
```